Python module organization with __init__.py file
Given a project structure which looks like
submodule
   __init__.py
   lib.py
   ClassDef.py
main.py

I'd like to be able to import the functions/classes which appear in helper.py with the following syntax:
import submodule as s

s.function_in_lib()

I tried the following syntax for __init__.py,
import submodule.ClassDef as l

ClassDef = l.ClassDef

I'm trying to avoid this situation with class definitions.
from submodule import ClassDef.ClassDef as ClassDef

I would much prefer
import submodule as s
tmp = s.ClassDef()

Is this possible for class definitions? It works with functions.

submodule.ClassDef() I advise against doing this - this will be a source of confusing error messages at best and bad bugs at worst. If you assign the name ClassDef inside __init__ (ClassDef = l.ClassDef), the import mechanism will no longer be able to access the module submodule.ClassDef from the point of this assignment onwards.

You can import class ClassDef into the namespace of submodule with this line in submodule/__init__.py:
from submodule.ClassDef import ClassDef

